# how to get value from expandable list view child value

Tags: android

I want to create custome expandable list view in android but when I click on child, no value found and my click event is given below:

```
mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Child clicked",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Anyone knows? please help
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.
Use method "getChildAtPosition"..

```
su chale chhe?
```

Comment: how can i get the entered value in this type expandable listview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739634/get-every-editbox-radio-button-value-when-is-clicked-in-expandable-child-elemen?noredirect=1#comment25863063_17739634