# How to get every value of EditBox and RadioButton, when I click on expandable child element?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, childviews

I have an expandable ListView, where every parentview has a child view.
In child view I have a sub-child element: EditText, TextView and RadioButton.

Child element have different value onclick on radiobutton and edittext value after entered

[image]

> CategoryActivity.java

```
   package com.restaurant.app;

    public class CategoryActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    public static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String TAG_PRICE="price";
    private static final String TAG_CATEGORY="category";
    private static final String TAG_DETAIL="detail";
    private static final String TAG_MENU="menu";
    private static final String TAG_ID="id";
    private static final String TAG_NOME="nome";
    private static final String TAG_HOTELID="hotel_id";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION="description";
    private static final String TAG_SERVICES="services";
    private static final String TAG_URLID="urlid";
    private static final String TAG_RESTAURANTID="restaurant_id";
    private static final String TAG_USERID="user_id";
    private static final String TAG_OFFERTA="offerta";
    private static final String TAG_PREZZO="prezzo";


    ArrayList<String> resultparent = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Object> resultchild = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> child = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


    // for childlist item
    ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> childlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>();

    ImageView imagehome;
    ImageView imagemenu;
    ImageView imagebooking;
    ImageView imageordernow;
    ExpandableListView expandablelistview;
    CategoryList categoryadapter;   
    SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.booking);   

        imagehome=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagehome);
        imagehome.setOnClickListener(this);

        imagemenu=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagemenu);
        imagemenu.setOnClickListener(this);

        imageordernow=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageordernow);
        imageordernow.setOnClickListener(this);

        expandablelistview = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandablelistview);    


        new CategoryAsynctask().execute("");

    }

    public class CategoryAsynctask extends AsyncTask<String,String,ArrayList<String>> 
    {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... arg0)
        {

            JsonParser jparser = new JsonParser();
            String url="http://cssthemeclub.com/demo/saffron/webservices/categorymenu.php?restid=5";
            String data=jparser.getJSONFromUrl(url);


            try
            {
                JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject(data);                
                JSONArray jcategory=jobject.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORY);

                Log.e("Category length","--->"+jcategory.length());

                for (int i=0;i<jcategory.length();i++)
                {   

                    JSONObject jdetail=jcategory.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(TAG_DETAIL);

                    String categoryid=jdetail.get(TAG_ID).toString();
                    String nome=jdetail.get(TAG_NOME).toString();
                    String restaurantid=jdetail.get(TAG_RESTAURANTID).toString();
                    resultparent.add(nome);

                    JSONArray jmenu = new JSONArray();
                    jmenu=null;
                    jmenu=jcategory.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(TAG_MENU);

                    //Log.e("Jmenu","--->"+jmenu);

                    child=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                    child.clear();

                    for(int j=0;j<jmenu.length();j++)
                    {                           
                            String menuid=jmenu.getJSONObject(j).getString(TAG_ID).toString();
                            String offer=jmenu.getJSONObject(j).getString(TAG_OFFERTA).toString();
                            String price=jmenu.getJSONObject(j).getString(TAG_PREZZO).toString();

                            //Log.e("menu","--->"+offer);
                            //Log.e("price","-->"+price);

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            map.put(TAG_MENU,menuid);
                            map.put(TAG_PREZZO,price);
                            map.put(TAG_OFFERTA,offer);
                            map.put(TAG_RESTAURANTID,restaurantid);

                            child.add(map);
                            childlist.add(child);

                    }
                    resultchild.add(child);

                }
                Log.e("Result Child","--->"+resultchild);

            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {

            }

            return resultparent;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result)
        {   
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            categoryadapter= new CategoryList(resultparent,resultchild);
            categoryadapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),CategoryActivity.this);
            expandablelistview.setAdapter(categoryadapter);

    }   
 }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            switch (v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.imagehome     : Intent home = new Intent(CategoryActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                                          startActivity(home);
                                          break;

                case R.id.imagemenu     : Intent menu = new Intent(CategoryActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
                                          startActivity(menu);  
                                          break;

                case R.id.imageordernow : Intent ordernow= new Intent(CategoryActivity.this,OrderDetailActivity.class);
                                          startActivity(ordernow); 
                                          break;

                default                 :   
                                          break;
            }
        }

    }
```

> Category List.java

```
public class CategoryList extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{   
    private static final String TAG_OFFERTA="offerta";
    private static final String TAG_PREZZO="prezzo";
    private static final String TAG_RESTAURANTID="restaurant_id";
    private static final String TAG_MENU="menu";
    private static final String TAG_ID="id";
    public Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<String> resultparent;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> tempchild; 
    public ArrayList<Object> resultchild=new ArrayList<Object>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> childlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    public LayoutInflater inflater = null;


    String id;
    String qty;
    String title;   
    String menuid;  
    String sessionid;
    String restorantid;
    String price;



    public CategoryList(ArrayList<String> grouplist,ArrayList<Object> childItem)
    {   
          resultparent=grouplist;
          this.resultchild = childItem;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act)
    {   
          this.inflater = mInflater;
          activity = act;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
    {   

        return null;
    }   

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {   

          tempchild = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)resultchild.get(groupPosition); 

          TextView textprice,textmenutitle;
          final EditText editqty;

          RadioGroup radiogroupchilli;
          RadioGroup radiogroupoil;

          final ImageView imagechilli;
          final ImageView imagechillitwo;

          final ImageView imageoil;
          final ImageView imagechiz;


         // RadioButton radiochillion,radiochillioff,radiooil,radiochiz;

          if(convertView == null)
          {  
              convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.redlistchild,null);
          }


          radiogroupchilli=(RadioGroup)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radiogroupchilli);
          radiogroupoil=(RadioGroup)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radiogroupoil);

          imagechilli=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagechilli);
          imagechillitwo=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagechillitwo);

          imageoil=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageoil);
          imagechiz=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagechiz);

          textprice=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textprice);
          textprice.setText(tempchild.get(childPosition).get(TAG_PREZZO).toString());

          textmenutitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textmenutitle);
          textmenutitle.setText(tempchild.get(childPosition).get(TAG_OFFERTA).toString());

          editqty=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editqty);       

          convertView.setTag(childPosition);

          radiogroupchilli.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
          {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
                {
                    switch(checkedId)
                    {
                        case R.id.radiochillion  : 
                                                   imagechillitwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.chilitwooff);
                                                   imagechilli.setImageResource(R.drawable.chilion);
                                                   break;

                        case R.id.radiochillioff : 
                                                   imagechillitwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.chilitwoon);
                                                   imagechilli.setImageResource(R.drawable.chilioff);
                                                   break;
                    }
                }

           });

          radiogroupoil.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
          {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
                {
                    switch(checkedId)
                    {
                        case R.id.radiooil  : 
                                              imageoil.setImageResource(R.drawable.oilon);
                                              imagechiz.setImageResource(R.drawable.chiijoff);
                                              break;

                        case R.id.radiochiz : 
                                              imageoil.setImageResource(R.drawable.oiloff);
                                              imagechiz.setImageResource(R.drawable.chijion);   
                                              break; 
                    }
                }

           });

          return convertView;

  }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {   

        return ((ArrayList<String>)resultchild.get(groupPosition)).size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) 
    {

        return resultparent.get(groupPosition);
    }


    @Override
    public int getGroupCount()
    {

        return resultparent.size();
    }



    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
    {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {   
         TextView texttitle;
         final LinearLayout nonvegtitlelistlayout;

         if(convertView == null)
         { 
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.redlistgroup, null);
         }

         nonvegtitlelistlayout=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nonvegtitlelistlayout);
         texttitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.texttitle);
         texttitle.setText(resultparent.get(groupPosition));

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() 
    {   
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {   
        return true;
    }

     @Override
     public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition)
     {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
     }

     @Override
     public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) 
     {
         super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
     }

}
```

Comment: if possible with any button than also suggest

Comment: can you elaborate your question and make it clear what you want to do?

Comment: ok i will put down the image

Comment: now you can check it out  i will put image in  that grouphav parent and edittext title,radio button is child which is expand now i want edittext value which is user entered and title and radiobutton image changed on anybutton click

Comment: @startandroid I corrected the title and the first part of your question (take a look, now is more readable). Just tell me: are you aiming on taking all Views data of your Layout, when you click on a specified element?

Comment: yes you are right i want to all the edittext and radio button how can i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of accessing view directly (by iterating through children of `ViewGroup`, which won't even work as you expect, since `ExpandableListView` recycles it's view as well as `ListView` does), you should store entered data into some sort of model.

In other words, while you're displaying data in list, it should be backed by some information (`String[]` in simpliest case). So, your task is to back displayed data with some specific class, which will hold information that you need. For example, you can name it `Option`.

Then, when you're editing data in `EditText`, you saving entered text into instance of `Option` that corresponds to current position of `ExpandableListView`. When you'll need to retrieve entered information, you just iterate through every `Option` that you saved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but you could try to get the children of each ViewGroup like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < viewGroup.getChildCount(); x++) {
    final View v = viewGroup.getChildAt(x);
    if(v instanceof EditText) {
        //do logic
    }
    else if(v instanceof RadioButton) {
        //do logic
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the ViewGroup object will be whatever is holding all of these views (LinearLayout, etc), so you would need to get a reference to that first.